# Does f:validateRegex render to javascript?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, mojarra

I have a p:inputText (PrimeFaces) with an included f:validateRegex field. I'm trying to make sure the entered information follows a format. Snippet:

```
<p:inputText id="usernameInput" required="true" validatorMessage="Invalid Email" value="#{sessionHandler.username}" >
    <f:validateRegex pattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$"/>
    <f:ajax event="keyUp" render="emailMessage" />
</p:inputText>
<p:watermark for="usernameInput" value="Email"/>
<h:message id="emailMessage" />
```

The f:validateRegex and f:ajax don't seem to be working (No message appears if incorrect format). When I look at the rendered HTML, I notice that both the f:validateRegex and f:ajax appear just as that and not as a rendered HTML component or javascript field. So, my question: is f:validateRegex supposed to render into javascript for the client side? If so, why is it not rendering correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. JSF is a HTML code generator. `<f:xxx>` tags are not HTML. Browsers only understand HTML, not JSF.

The symptoms indicate that you forgot to declare the `f:` XML namespace in a parent element. E.g.

```
<html ... xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
```

This way, you should not see anything related to `<f:validateRegex>` at all. It's namely entirely server side. The `<f:ajax>` should translate to a script in some HTML DOM event attribute, such as `onkeyup` when you use `keyup` (and thus not `keyUp`).

Comment: I'm getting an "NLS missing message" warning on my namespace. I believe I may have used the incorrect namespace. I used `xmlns:f="http:/java.sun.com/jsf/core"`

Comment: That's the old JSF 2.0/2.1 namespace which should however work equally good on JSF 2.2. Try upgrading Mojarra. In versions 2.2.0/2.2.1/2.2.2 there were some bugs in XML namespace registration. If the error still persists, then just ignore and run it and verify in browser is everything generates well. If so, then it's likely just your editor (the IDE) who in turn needs a upgrade.